# Write plugin for VideoJS 5

Tags: javascript, video.js

When I trying to use the newest version of videojs 5, the following code is no longer worked. I am trying to write a videojs plugin, but videojs 5 use ecmascript 6, which is new to me. Any helps are appreciated.

```
   videojs.SharingButton = videojs.Button.extend({
    /** @constructor */
    init: function(player, options){
        videojs.Button.call(this, player, options);
        this.player = player;
    }
});

videojs.SharingButton.prototype.createEl = function(tagName,options) {
    return videojs.Component.prototype.createEl(tagName,{
        className: this.buildCSSClass(),
        innerHTML: '',
        role: 'button',
        'aria-live': 'polite', // let the screen reader user know that the text of the button may change
        tabIndex: 0
    });
}

videojs.SharingButton.prototype.buttonText = 'Share Video';

videojs.SharingButton.prototype.options_ = {};

videojs.SharingButton.prototype.buildCSSClass = function(){
    return 'vjs-sharing-control ';
};
```

Comment: I don't see anything here related to ES6.

Comment: Videojs 5 was wrote by ES6, I am trying to rewrite my plugin. My plugin will not use ES6.

Comment: Then this should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i had the same problem, Replace this Code

`videojs.SharingButton = videojs.Button.extend({`

by

```
var SharingButton = videojs.getComponent('Button');
videojs.SharingButton = videojs.extend(SharingButton , {...});
videojs.registerComponent('SharingButton', SharingButton);

var myButton = myPlayer.addChild('SharingButton');
```

If you want to add a Component that is not a direct child of the player element you will have to climb the child elements and add the Component.
Like:

```
parentComponent = myPlayer.getChild('component1').getChild('component2')...
parentComponent.addChild('SharingButton')
```

Beware that the player components have to start lowercase like e.g. `controlBar`.

Find the component tree in this [link](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/components.md).

A lot of changes has being made as version 5.0 is built (see this [link](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/5.0-Change-Details)), and unfortunately most videojs plugins didn't make an update of their codes! one of theme is Social button sharing